# struts2 fileupload maximum size error showing in form page

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I am using struts2 for file uploading .When the file size exceeds configured length it is giving

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
```

How i can show in my form page this error.Because it is raising in interceptor.

Comment: Did you exceeded the File limit or the overall Multipart limit ?

Comment: You need to catch exception before the interceptor stack applied to the action.

Comment: @PSR Why do you ask me it? Do you want to post the answer?

Comment: @java.mypassion Show us what did you try.

Answer (score 0):

Define an `input` result for your Action, pointing to the same JSP of the `success` result.

In JSP, check for actionErrors or fieldErrors, and print them if there are, like:

```
<s:if test="actionErrors != null && actionErrors.size > 0">
    <div class="feed_ko">
        <s:actionerror escape="false" />
    </div>
</s:if>
<s:if test="fieldErrors != null && fieldErrors.size > 0">
    <div class="feed_ko">
        <s:fielderror />
    </div>
</s:if>
```